# Google app engine launcher while browsing project "No such projects are selected"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-3.x, google-app-engine-python

I have created folder that is apps, and that having the subfolder that is ae-01-trivial.Added app.yaml to the ae-01-trivial,

Following code are added to the app.yaml:

```
application: ae-01-trivial
version: 1
runtime: python34
api_version: 1
handlers: -
url: /.* 
script: index.py
```

And also added index.py to the ae-01-trivial, it is having following code:

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ' '
print 'Hello there Chuck' .
```

So here I have facing the problem is "**no such projects are selected**".

Comment: This question is very unclear.  Where did you create apps folder?  Can you format the code in Following code ...?  What do you mean by 'enter code here?  Can you format the code 'print 'Content ...'  Where did the error message come from?

Comment: Side note: I see the Q tagged with `python-3.x` - that's not (yet) supported on GAE

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a request handler in App Engine, follow [this example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/). Also Google App Engine uses Python 2.7 runtime for Python applications, so 3.4 may not work.